# Is there a way to insert variables in other shortcodes with Quarto?

Tags: quarto

Using variables with quarto is straight forward (see https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/variables.html).
Lets say I have e.g. a `_variables.yml` file with some variable `website: https://stackoverflow.com` and I want to use other shortcodes such as the Qrcode Extension for Quarto (https://github.com/jmbuhr/quarto-qrcode).

Is there a way I can insert a variable in the other shortcode?
Such as `{{< qrcode {{< var website >}} >}}` instead of `{{< qrcode https://github.com/jmbuhr/quarto-qrcode >}}`?